# STM32 I2C1 Start bit not set on SR1 register

Tags: c, embedded, i2c, stm32

I am trying to program the stm32 to talk to my i2c EEprom, but it seems like everytime I say:

```
I2C_GenerateSTART(I2C1, ENABLE);
while( !(I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_MODE_SELECT)) );  the code hangs here
```

I went through with the debugger and I found that the SR1 bit 0 flag (which is the start bit generated flag) is not set which is why the code hangs. I can see in the oscilloscope that the start bit was generated and this works sometimes. it usually breaks when I tried to do several writes in a row. I checked the HW is everything looks fine I checked the frequency that I am running on the i2c bus it is 100Khz well within the 24lc1025 eeprom.

any ideas,

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you say that this usually breaks when you're doing several writes in a row, you might want to ensure that you're not violating this note in the STM32 datasheet for the `STOP` bit in the I2C_CR1 control register:

> Note: When the `STOP`, `START` or `PEC` bit is set, the software must not perform any write
>   access to `I2C_CR1` before this bit is cleared by hardware. Otherwise there is a risk of
>   setting a second `STOP`, `START` or `PEC` request.

Once you set the `STOP` bit you need to make sure that the hardware has cleared it before you write the next `START` bit.

Comment: Thank you. I will check this on monday I know for sure that I am not checking if the STOP bit has been cleared so this could be the root of all my problems. I dont know how I missed that in the datasheet.

Comment: Well, it's kind of non-obvious since it's not in a status register. But then again, there's almost always some non-obvious stuff in hardware registers - that's why drivers are hard.

Comment: Quick update I tried doing what you said, and it did fix the problem for the start bit. Now there is something else, after I send the slave address the device does not respond. this is when I try to to two writes in a row when I try one it works fine. I check in the scope and the signals look fine. the EEprom is just not acking after its address is sent. I checked make sure the address does not change between writes and it doesnt also if I put a delay of 5ms in between writes then it works with consecutive writes. I am running at 100khz bus this EEprom the 24lc1025 can run up to 1Mhz any ideas

Comment: @jramirez: The EEPROM is working to spec there - it can take up to 5ms for a write command to complete its cycle (Parameter 17 - TWC - in the datasheet's "AC Characteristics" table).  You can either delay between write requests or use the "Acknowledge Polling" technique described in section 7.0 and Figure 7-1 of the datasheet.

Comment: haha yes I did find that on Friday I meant to post it, but I forgot. Thank you so much for the help. I gotta remember to read the whole datasheet instead of thinking "I2C no problem let's code it" then wonder why it doesnt work as intended that will come with experience I hope :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, it definitely helped me out. I ended up calling "I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2Cx, I2C_FLAG_STOPF)" after generating the stop condition which seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Errata for your device (get it from the ST website). The STM32 has a lot of bugs in the I2C implementation. The errata gives software workarounds for them.

Answer (score 0):

Also, when using the driver source files typically provided with STM32 platforms, don't forget to read through the headers! They can be very helpful, especially for novices (like me) who aren't sure where to start.

In this case, you would be looking at [stm32f4xx_i2c.c](http://web.eece.maine.edu/~hummels/classes/ece486/docs/libperiph_doc/stm32f4xx__i2c_8c_source.html)